# Algorithm to reflect octant of a square matrix all seven ways

Tags: java, c, arrays, algorithm, matrix

In a square matrix of even dimension `s` there are `s/4(s/2+1)` types of squares which can be reflected seven different ways around the matrix. For example, a 10 x 10 matrix has the unique squares colored in the figure below:

[image: octant]

These 15 squares can be reflected around the horizontal, vertical and diagonal axes of the matrix in 7 different ways.

Assuming there are unique values assigned to each type of such element of an n x n array where n is an even number, what is the most efficient way to populate the matrix (in C or Java)? In other words, given a list of 15 values in any structure you wish, you need to populate the rest of the 10 x 10 array with the 15 values by reflections. What is the fastest algorithm to do this?

As an example, here is my first try at this (note that it uses one-based arrays):

```
public static int[][] valueSquare = new int[11][11];
public static int[][] valueSquareType = {
        { 0, 40,  2, 12, 15, 20 },
        { 0,  2,  1,  4,  8, 12 },
        { 0, 12,  4, 25, 20, 15 },
        { 0, 15,  8, 20, 22, 18 },
        { 0, 20, 12, 15, 18,  0 },
};
static {
    for( int x = 1; x <= 5; x++ ) for( int y = 1; y <= 5; y++ ) valueSquare[ 11 - x ][ y ] = valueSquareType[x][y];
    for( int x = 1; x <= 5; x++ ) for( int y = 1; y <= 5; y++ ) valueSquare[ 11 - x ][ 11 - y ] = valueSquareType[x][y];
    for( int x = 1; x <= 5; x++ ) for( int y = 1; y <= 5; y++ ) valueSquare[ x ][ 11 - y ] = valueSquareType[x][y];
}
```

One objection to this is that it has a redundant starter array which is reflected 3 ways, instead of a minimal starter array reflected 7 ways. Ideally, I would like a starter array, with just the 15 key values. Also, the looping in my try may not be the fastest approach.

Comment: Your matrix only has `9` rows, and I think you're missing some brackets here: `s/4(s/2+1)`?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why not writing explicitly the seven loops needed to fill the matrix ? By doing this properly you only consider each index exactly once and therefore only perform the needed assignments.

Comment: @IVlad I have updated the image to have 10 rows.

Comment: @Eregrith I provided an example of code which is my initial try at the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is what you mean:

[image]

Given the black area in the upper left, then we just need to iterate all elements `(i, j)` in that area and compute their location in the other areas after mirroring (diagonals overlap so I marked them as gray, but the formulas consider them too and you can apply them to the given diagonal elements too):

Assuming 0-indexing

```
(i, j) -> (i, n - j - 1)          # red area
       -> (j, n - i - 1)          # yellow area
       -> (j, i)                  # teal area
       -> (n - i - 1, j)          # green area
       -> (n - i - 1, n - j - 1)  # blue area
       -> (n - j - 1, n - i - 1)  # pink area
       -> (n - j - 1, i)          # orange area
```

So iterate each given black element and copy it to the 7 positions in the other areas. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int v[6][6] = {
        { 0, 3,  2, 12, 15, 20 },
        { 0,  2,  1,  4,  8, 12 },
        { 0, 12,  4, 25, 20, 15 },
        { 0, 15,  8, 20, 22, 18 },
        { 0, 20, 12, 15, 18,  0 },
};


int main()
{
    int n = 6;
    // iterate given black area:
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n / 2; ++j)
        {
            v[i][n - j - 1] = v[i][j]; // copy to red
            v[j][n - i - 1] = v[i][j]; // copy to yellow
            v[j][i] = v[i][j]; // copy to teal
            v[n - i - 1][j] = v[i][j]; // copy to green
            v[n - i - 1][n - j - 1] = v[i][j]; // copy to blue
            v[n - j - 1][n - i - 1] = v[i][j]; // copy to pink
            v[n - j - 1][i] = v[i][j]; // copy to orange;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 3 2 2 3 0
3 2 1 1 2 3
2 1 4 4 1 2
2 1 4 4 1 2
3 2 1 1 2 3
0 3 2 2 3 0
```

Which seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something what can be faster than this ?

```
for (int i = 1; i < n/2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        M[i][j] = M[j][i]; // first complete the first quadrant
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i<n/2; i++) {
    for (int j = n/2; j < n; j++) {
        // then perform the three needed symmetries
        M[i][j] = M[i][n-j-1];
        M[n-i-1][j] = M[i][n-j-1];
        M[n-i-1][n-j-1] = M[i][n-j-1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would think that you make the diagonal reflection. Then you have a quater of the matrix filled. This is the trickiest part I guess because every column has a different length. Maybe something like this:
4 = s/2-1 and 10 = s

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
{
  for(int i=j;i<4;i++)
  {
   array[i+1][j]=array[j][i+1];
  }
}
```

Then you just have to mirror it in diagonally and horizontally.

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
   array[i][j]=array[9-i][j];
  }
}
```

and

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
   array[i][j]=array[i][9-j];
  }
}
```

If there are some optimzed functions to copy memory and flip it, they would be better, but I don't know any.
For larger matrices it would be useful to use multiple threads(as many as you have cores). With this size I am not certain it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on IVlad's answer. Depending on what you'd like to do with the populated matrix, this version with pointers allows you to vary any of the "starter array" values and watch it instantly be reflected in the eight octants (see example). I grouped the formulas in the example to show that each octant can be reflected in four ways horizontally and four ways vertically, the vertical versions being a simple transposition of the horizontal, switching `i`'s for `j`'s.

```
void showArray(int *arr[][8]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        cout << *arr[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main(){
  int d[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  int n = 8; int *v[8][8]; int k = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i){
    for (int j = i; j < n / 2; ++j){
        v[i][j] = &d[k];
        v[j][i] = &d[k];

        v[i][n - j - 1] = &d[k];
        v[j][n - i - 1] = &d[k];

        v[n - i - 1][j] = &d[k];
        v[n - j - 1][i] = &d[k]; 

        v[n - i - 1][n - j - 1] = &d[k];
        v[n - j - 1][n - i - 1] = &d[k];

        k++;
    }
  }

  showArray(v); cout << endl;
  d[2] = 44;
  showArray(v);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0 
1 4 5 6 6 5 4 1 
2 5 7 8 8 7 5 2 
3 6 8 9 9 8 6 3 
3 6 8 9 9 8 6 3 
2 5 7 8 8 7 5 2 
1 4 5 6 6 5 4 1 
0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0 

0 1 44 3 3 44 1 0 
1 4 5 6 6 5 4 1 
44 5 7 8 8 7 5 44 
3 6 8 9 9 8 6 3 
3 6 8 9 9 8 6 3 
44 5 7 8 8 7 5 44 
1 4 5 6 6 5 4 1 
0 1 44 3 3 44 1 0
```